# How does "Autoclose braces" work in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

[image]

When I enable the option and enter an opening bracket (or brace) it does not auto-close itself. Does auto-close have a different meaning than what I am understanding?

Comment: For me, this works with JavaScript. So the question was already a good enough answer for me, when I wanted to find out how to do this with NPP :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [xbrackets lite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XBrackets%20Lite/) plugin for notepad++ does bracket and brace closing for all (I guess) types of files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a new file or one with an unrecognized file extension, have you set a **language** (i.e. `Menu > Language`)? The TextFX option for auto-closing braces requires a language to be set (e.g. C, Java, PHP, etc).

Comment: I already set the language (.R) and NP++ has the syntax highlighted. Yet, I do not find the braces closing automatically when I type '('.

Comment: I could not find any documentation on the feature, but it appears that some languages are not supported.