# Notepad++ inserts braces with commas, how to disable it?

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete

Notepad++ has very annoying feature of inserting braces with commas for lines that contain interpunction and I'm unable to find out how to stop it.

For example, If I type:

```
hello, I don't want braces. Simply, no
```

And press ENTER, Notepad++ inserts

```
( , ,  )
```

into new line.

It's not [parenthesis autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119387/how-to-disable-annoying-parenthesis-completion)  or [textfx](https://superuser.com/questions/404679/how-does-autoclose-braces-work-in-notepad), so I'm out of ideas here.

Anyone knows what I need to disable to get rid of that behavior?

Comment: What encoding are you using by default?

Comment: I would think it's encoding as well, I just tried it and can't recreate the problem

Comment: What is the file type?

Comment: The file is plain simple .txt, the encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here, looks like it was NppCalc plugin, try disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Juraj's answer, NppCalc is definitely the culprit.  However, you don't have to completely disable the plugin.  Instead, you just need to turn off the "Active Calc" feature of it.

There are three ways to accomplish this:

1. Uncheck "Active Calc" from the NppCalc submenu under the Plugin menu
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+C
3. Click the Active Calc button in the toolbar (it looks like a calculator)